# Tools or scripts to transfer files of a specific criteria to a USB drive

Tags: backup, filesystems, batch-file, data-recovery

The company I work for has a 'company wide' share that is mapped on all of our machines. Over the years this has grown into the terrabytes and now lucky me has been tasked with bringing this back under control.

I'm looking for a robust script/utility that can find files by the following criteria and move them to a 1TB USB drive that I've purchased...

- files not modified in the last 10 years
- that are over 3mb in size

The script will need to recreate the folder structure on the USB drive, so if we have a member of staff who decides they need one of these files we can get it back easily.

Note: The company does have proper offsite backups of this data, the USB drive is just to enable quicker access to the data if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hands down best method for moving files/folders from a source system is to use robocopy in my opinion.  You should look at the [TechNet reference on Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) for the proper syntax.

In glancing at the "File Selection Options" you will want to use a combination of /min:3072000 and /minage:3650 or /minlad:3650.  Regardless, there are innumerable options there for you to review.

Comment: Thanks I cant believe I'd never come across robocopy before!

Comment: Glad to be of service.  I've never had to use the file filtering options as I was just trying to get files from x to y.  But I love how you can specify many threads.